# What are the native cookies Magento has?

Tags: magento2, cookie, gdpr

What's the list of out-of-the-box cookies on Magento OpenSource and Adobe Commerce Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Default Cookies

The default cookies in Adobe Commerce and Magento Open Source are classified as Exempt / Non-Exempt to help merchants meet the requirements of privacy regulations such as the GDPR.

#### Requested functionality cookies (exempt)

- add_to_cart
- guest-view
- login_redirect
- mage-banners-cache-storage
- mage-messages
- mage-translation-storage
- mage-translation-file-version
- product_data_storage
- recently_compared_product
- recently_compared_product_previous
- recently_viewed_product
- recently_viewed_product_previous
- remove_from_cart
- stf
- X-Magento-Vary
- form_key
- mage-cache-sessid
- mage-cache-storage
- mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation
- persistent_shopping_cart
- private_content_version
- section_data_ids
- store
- mage-banners-cache-storage

**Reference:** [Adobe Commerce Default Cookies](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/start/compliance/privacy/compliance-cookie-law.html?lang=en#default-cookies)